# FFMpeg - convert all audio streams from MKV to MP4

Tags: ffmpeg

I have MKV file which contains:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High)
Stream #0:1(pol): Audio: ac3
Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: dts (DTS)
Stream #0:3(pol): Subtitle: subrip
Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle:  hdmv_pgs_subtitle
```

I would like to omit subtitles (`-sn` option), copy video and encode audio streams to AAC.

I tried few various command and output file is always the same (2 audio streams but in both sound from first audio stream).

Here are my commands:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -sn -map 0:a? -map 0:v -c:v copy -c:a? aac output.mp4 
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -sn -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4 
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -sn -map 0:? -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Everything almost work but in output file I have 2 audio streams with name (pol) and (eng) but in both is sound from (pol) stream0:1.

What command should I use to convert audio streams in order to achieve two a audio streams where will be pol and eng sound (not pol in both of them). Sometimes input file has only 1 audio stream so to command line should be universal, I guess ffmpeg map with `?` character.

Answer (score 8):

## If the streams in the MKV file are compatible with MP4

You can remux with [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) mode (`-c copy`). This avoids re-encoding.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy output.mp4
```

- `-map 0` selects all streams from input #0 which is `input.mkv` (note that  `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0). Otherwise the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior is used which will only select one stream per stream type.
- `ffmpeg` will tell you if a stream is not compatible with the output container format with an error message: `codec not currently supported in container`.
- Currently the most typical compatible formats are: H.264 video, H.265/HEVC video, and AAC audio.

## Excluding incompatible streams

You can use negative mapping. Example to include everything except subtitles:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -map -0:s -c copy output.mp4
```

See the [`-map` option documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) for more info.

## Re-encoding incompatible streams

This example stream copies everything except for audio which is converted to AAC:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Obviously all posted here commands are correct. The problem was my media player which read always the same no matter i choose.

Comment: @Andrew541 What media player are you using?

Comment: It wasn't exactly media player. I tried to play it on Emby media server, in google chrome, but in chrome there is no API to select secondary audio tracks.

Comment: @llogan - Hi, I have tried this, it work however I get this message. `Multiple -c, -codec, -acodec, -vcodec, -scodec or -dcodec options specified for stream 1, only the last option '-c:a aac' will be used.` Not sure if it is something to be worried about? This is the code I used: `for /R %f IN (*.mkv) DO ffmpeg -v warning -hide_banner -stats -i "%f" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy -c:a aac "%~nf.mp4"` based off you code. Thank you

Comment: @llogan - I had to create an answer in order to put all the information there.

Comment: @llogan, Ah, you learn something everyday. Here we go: https://pastebin.com/1DZtX7fZ

Comment: @llogan Right, here we go. Thank you: https://pastebin.com/AGpUgrvY

Comment: @Arthor Since all of your input streams are already MP4 compatible just use: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy output.mp4`

Comment: @llogan, Going to give it a go. Thank you

Comment: In the last example how do you copy everything (video, audio, subs) and add an AAC audio track, not replace it? Seems impossible

Comment: @malhal `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i audio.aac -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv`

Comment: Sorry I don't mean add from file I mean convert.

Comment: @malhal Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: youtube-dl video have to use `Re-encoding incompatible streams` to get the audio out

Comment: @Arthor The reason you get that error message is because the first `-c copy` argument covers all of the stream types (video, audio, subtitle). You're telling it to copy the audio stream, then encode the audio stream with `-c:a aac`. Try this instead:
`for /R %f IN (*.mkv) DO ffmpeg -v warning -hide_banner -stats -i "%f" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v copy -c:a aac "%~nf.mp4"`